# Why does my React Native camera feature give an 'OpenCamera() does not work or load' error on iOS simulator in Xcode?

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera

So I'm making this application which has a feature of taking pictures using the phone's camera but when I click the button which opens the phone's camera it displays an error which says that `OpenCamera()` does not work or load, idk if its because im using an iOS simulator on Xcode but I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

I tried different methods provided by YouTube but sadly none worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the fact that the iOS simulator doesn't support the camera. You will not be able to open the camera or take a photo in the iOS simulator. Instead, you will need to test this feature on a real device.

Refer [this](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1418) issue on GitHub.